# Issues with the OR clause

Tags: t-sql

I am having some trouble with the OR clause.
I am trying to join two large tables and given below is a sample data from the tables

**Table1 (t1)**

```
      vendor        addr1           city         zip
       ADT      PO BOX 371956      PITSBURGH     15250
```

**Table2  (t2)**

```
      vendor    addr1       city             zip
      ADT   PO Box 371956   Pittsburgh      15250-7956
```

The first two select statements given below display one row of data from the two tables. 
In the third select, I have an OR clause and this does not display any rows. 
The OR clause should not affect the result set.

```
 select *
 from t1
 left join t2
 on t1.addr1 = t2.addr1


  select *
   from t1
  left join t2
  on t1.addr1 = t2.addr1
   and (t1.city = t2.city)
```

**the select below does not display any data.     WHY?**

```
 select *
  from t1
 left join t2
 on t1.addr1 = t2.addr1
 and ((t1.city = t2.city) or (t1.zip = t2.zip))
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your or statement is comparing zips and cities, whereas your previous statements are comparing cities and addresses. The zip codes of your tables do not appear to be the same (table one does not have the hyphenated portion), and neither are the cities (Pit vs. Pitt in the spelling for one thing). If this is the actual data, it's because the data does not match.

Comment: But it is an OR clause and since the city matches, it does not matter if the zip matches or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your last query you have:

```
t1.addr1 = t2.addr2 AND
(
    t1.city = t2.city OR
    t1.zip  = t2.zip
)
```

Considering your sample data:

```
t1."PO BOX 371956" = t2."PO Box 371956" AND -- TRUE
(
    t1."PITSBURGH" = t2."Pittsburgh" OR     -- FALSE
    t1."15250" = t2."15250-7956"            -- FALSE
)
```

You got:

```
= TRUE AND (FALSE OR FALSE)
= TRUE AND FALSE
= FALSE
```

So, no soup for you.

Comment: But then OP query two should not return a row either.